# Send to server float array using libcurl c++

Tags: c++, django, http, libcurl, portaudio

I am using a portaudio callback where I receive periodically a buffer of audio and store it on **main_buffer**. I only set the settings bellow for curl and only use the **CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** to set the float buffer before sending it with **curl_easy_perform**. On the server side I am using python django:

```
float main_buffer[256];

url_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);

//portaudio periodic callback
callback(){
  //...
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, main_buffer);
  curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```

The request received in server has no content inside body. How to send main_buffer the right way ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to serialise the data that you send, and then deserialise what you receive. There is no "the right way". There are several ways with different advantages.

In your case, I recommend starting with a simple way. Simplest portable way to serialise floating point is to use textual encoding. A commonly used textual format that can represent arrays is JSON. For example, the array `float[] main_buffer{1.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f}` could be encoded as `[1.0,1.5,2.0]`.

The reading part in Python is quite simple:

```
json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'));
```

The writing part in C++ is a bit more complex. There is no standard way to encode JSON in C++. You can use a full encoder based on the [specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), or you could write an ad-hoc loop for this specific case:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << '[';
const char* separator = "";
for (float f : main_buffer) {
    ss << separator << f;
    separator = ",";
}
ss << ']';
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ss.str().c_str());
curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

Comment: There are plenty of JSON libraries for C++. But you don't have to serialize the array into a string format at all if you use a binary `Content-Type` like `application/octet-stream` instead. Just use [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE.html) to specify the byte size of the array so `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` won't treat it as a null-terminated string, eg: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, sizeof(main_buffer)); curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, reinterpret_cast<char*>(main_buffer));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau They certainly could use binary, but then they must understand what endianness is, and how to handle the case where server and client have different endianness. And of course the case of differing floating point representation although that might not become an issue in practice. And reading the binary in Python is not going to be quite as trivial either (although `numpy` makes it easy).

Comment: Greetings thank you for your reply!
I tried the suggestion provided by eerorika. It's easier for me to work with json as need to add more information on the request but I can't decode it in server side:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @Jolozangui You could try something like `ss.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"));` to make sure that the written string is encoded correctly. The name of the locale depends on the operating system and its configuration though. That said, I'm quite surprised about 0xc5 being there. I don't know what encoding would result in that. Did you make any changes to my example, or did you use a JSON encoder?

Comment: @eerorika I tried the solution exactly as posted and added the suggestion of your last comment but i still can't decode the request.

Comment: @Jolozangui Does the output look correct if you print it in C++?

Comment: @eerorika Yes it does.

Comment: @Jolozangui Then I would check what the exact contents of `request.body` are in Python.

Comment: @eerorika Something like this: b'\xb0\xc3\x1b\x01\xa6\x01'

Comment: @Jolozangui There's no `0xc5` in that array ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @eerorika I think I fixed it, I was using my float array. Instead of using ss.str() I used ss.str().c_str(). Does this make sense ? but now it throws an Access violation excepction after the first request on libcurl: data->state.infilesize = (curl_off_t)strlen(data->set.postfields);. What am I missing now ?